# Firebase value to localstorage

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, local-storage

I am a beginner learning Javascript and I am making a game. 
The highscore is set into localstorage at this moment. Now I'm learning a firebase database, and the highscore is updating to firebase, but when I refresh it start again at 0 because it updates when score > highscore.

I want to set the localstorage highscore to the firebase value when I reloading the page.

I tried the following:

```
localStorage.setItem("highscore", firebase.database().ref('/score/currentHighscore').once('value'));
```

but this does't work. Any help?

My highscore in firebase is under score -> currentHighscore.

Comment: Can you show more of your code? In particular the lines that surround the line you have shown. I suspect you are doing the storage in local storage before you receive the result of the asynchronous once() method. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once and note how the username is populated: in the then()

Comment: Sure @RenaudT. I put the a part of the code in JSFiddle, if you want the hole code of the game, then say it and i will put the whole game in a JSfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/nzr8ukqa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in my comment above, the once method is asynchronous, so you should do something like:

```
return firebase.database().ref('/score').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    var highScore = snapshot.val().currentHighscore; //maybe test here it is not null
    localStorage.setItem("highscore", highScore);
});
```

I would advice you have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once

Comment: Thanks for your answer Renaud